# Windows 8 on Sony Vaio Fit - I have lost the @ key

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, language

I have somehow done something on the language settings and now the <kbd>'</kbd> / <kbd>@</kbd> key isn't working at all.
I have set he language as English UK and keyboard set in Windows 8.
If I change to e.g. US English, I can use the <kbd>2</kbd> keypad button, and the  <kbd>@</kbd> keys for `"`. What is going on?

Comment: Why isn't your keyboard set to English UK if your os language is set to that?

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, the @ key is in a different place in the UK layout - on the second/home row, the last three keys (left most, next to the reverse L shaped enter key) are <kbd>;</kbd> <kbd>@</kbd> <kbd>#</kbd>, with the alternate keys being ; ' and #. On the numbers row, the left most key does a backtick/ a | and a funny symbol and 3 is the pound sign and 2 is the "

(and, wikipedia to the rescue!)

The british use the layout below - though my one british keyboard lacks the blue accented letter keys

[image]

and the 'common' qwerty seems to be the ansi layout

[image]

([via wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:KB_United_Kingdom.svg))